# How to cleanly exit a QProcess with Ctrl+C input?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qprocess

I am running a QProcess event that exits when pushing Ctrl+C directly in cmd. How can I send a signal from python to close down the process cleanly? I've tryed kill() which doesn't let the program save accordingly. Also terminate() doesn't respond. I hope you can help.

```
    self.btn_1 = QPushButton('Start')
    self.btn_1.clicked.connect(self.start)

    self.btn_2 = QPushButton('Stop')
    self.btn_1.clicked.connect(self.stop)

    self.process = QProcess()

def start(self):
    self.process.start("C:\path\program.exe")

def stop(self):
    print('Stop the process!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the process PID then you can send the signal via `os.kill`:

```
import os
import signal 

os.kill(<pid>, signal.SIGINT) #SIGINT is CTRL-C
```

You get the PID from the `QProcess` object with:

```
pid = self.process.processId()
```

**EDIT**: on Windows, replace SIGINT with CTRL_C_EVENT

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works for shutting down the process, however, it takes some time to save the data (e.g. 2 seconds) and it kills the process too quickly. Do you know of some way to wait until finished saving the data?

Comment: I got it to work. I had to change SIGINT to CTRL_C_EVENT. Thanks for the help!